# Ruby—how to loop through indefinite user input

Tags: ruby, input

So I have a little ruby program I run on the console.

Sometimes I want to type input in (as much as I want, until I ctrl+c outta there), sometimes I want to put a file as input (e.g. `ruby robot_simulator.rb < test_data.txt`)

Currently I have this code:

```
while(true)
  input = gets.chomp
```

It kind of works, but when I run it with a file as input, it finishes by crashing with this error:

```
robot_simulator.rb:23:in `<main>': undefined method `chomp' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

Is there a nice way to continuously get input from console/files?

Comment: Parens are optional and you omitted the `end`--you don't by chance happend to be a Python programmer? ;-)

Comment: Can you not use `Kernel#loop` for this?

Comment: @MarkThomas I excluded all the other code, including the final `end`—I'm ruby all the way!

Comment: @iceツ yes, I forgot :P

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `while(true)`

It should be something more like `while(input = gets)`

If the `chomp` is necessary, use the (ruby 2.3) `&` operator, so that it only runs if `gets` is not `nil`:

`while(input = gets&.chomp)`